# Passing lambda expression from method... What's wrong with is code?

Tags: lambda, java-8, arguments, predicate

```
import java.util.function.Predicate;

class Test {
    // lambda expression can be passed as first argument in the check() method
    static boolean check(Predicate ti, int b) {
        return ti.test(b);
    }
}
public class ClassCuncurrentModExcep {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        // lambda expression
        boolean result = Test.check((x) -> (x%2) == 0, 10);
        System.out.println("The result is: "+ result);
    }
}
```

> The operator `%` is undefined for the argument type(s) Object, int while passing lambda as argument to Test.check().

Also what would be a standard way to create predicate expressions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which type is your Predicate expecting.

```
class Test {
    // lambda expression can be passed as first argument in the check() method
    static boolean check(Predicate<Integer> ti, int b) {
        return ti.test(b);
    }
}
```